# Applescript scraping webpage

Tags: applescript, scrape

there is this awesome website called www.engrade.com. You can get your grades from the website when you log in from your various classes.

Now, is it possible for an Applescript to parse engrade.com, log in as me, using my username and password, then parse to find my grade?

can some one show an example of this? especially logging in.

Thanks,
Elijah

Comment: Scraping websites is hard. Scraping websites with Applescript is just masochistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a language like Python to do this.  Why do you want to do it with Applescript?